# get count of a value from multiple table

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables

### tbl1

```
ID     | ID1    |  ID2
------ | ------ | ------
1      | 3      |   5
```

### tbl2

```
   ID     | NAME   |  ID2
   ------ | ------ | ------
   1      | RAJ    |   5
   2      | SAM    |   3
   3      | RAM    |   5
   4      | RIO    |   2
   5      | ROY    |   5
   6      | TIM    |   5
```

Now what i am struggling to do was ,

Take the ID2 in tbl1 i.e., 5 then get the rows of ID2 in tbl2 with the value 5

Now count the number of rows with 5 in tbl2

check whether it is greater than or less than the value of ID1 in tbl1 i.e, 3

if greater then echo true else echo false .

In the above case it will be true as we have 4 entries of 5 which is greater than 3.

Kindly guide me how to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM
                t2, t1
            WHERE
                t1.id2 = t2.id2) > t1.id1,
        'true', 'false') AS result
FROM
    t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need something like. But it might behave incorrectly if you have more that 1 row in `tbl1` with `ID2` as `5`

```
select 
case when (select count(*) from tbl1 
                    inner join tbl2  
                        on tbl1.id2=tbl2.id2 and tbl1.id2=5
          ) > ID1 
    then 'TRUE' 
    else 'FALSE' 
end as result;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will be giving you the result for each row of *tbl1*:

```
select  tbl1.id, tbl1.id1, tbl1.id2, 
        case when cnt.num > tbl1.id1 then 'TRUE'
             else 'FALSE'
        end as chk
  from  tbl1
        left join (
                    select  count(*) as num
                      from  tbl2
                     where  tbl2.id2 = tbl1.id2
                  ) cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a query for that this way

```
select  t1.ID2, case when cnt > ID1 then 'true' else 'false' end
from    (
            select  t1.ID2, t1.ID1, count(*) cnt
            from    tbl1 t1
            join    tbl2 t2
            on      t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
            group by t1.ID2, t1.ID1
        ) t1
```

Comment: I am getting a error in phpmyadmin as "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias" for this query mate

Comment: Yeah that's fixed thanks but now it fetches the corresponding row but the true or false is not been taken. It's just fetching the row

Answer (score 1):

```
select * , count(*), if(count(*) = t1.ID1, true, false) Result 
from t1
  inner join t2 on t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
group by t2.ID2
```

Comment: if join is possible, then sub-query must be avoided. Like what will happen when there are millions of rows in table? offcourse sub-query is not always feasible.